# Un hivernage fécond - Qu’est-ce que c’est ?

Tags: sens

Salut,

Je viens de lire [ce tweet](https://twitter.com/mohamedbazoum/status/1417402834253930520?s=21) du Président Nigérien. Je ne comprends pas la dernière phrase de ce tweet :

> Je prie pour qu'Il nous gratifie d'un hivernage fécond.

Qu’est-ce qu’un hivernage fécond ?

Merci par avance.

Comment: [Hivernage](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/hivernage), [fécond](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/f%C3%A9cond). Il semble que ce soit une expression traditionnelle liée à la religion musulmane et ce n'est pas sur FL que la réponse sera donnée quant au sens dans le contexte  dans lequel il est employé par le président nigérian.

Comment: @None Non, ce n'est pas une expression traditionnelle liée à une religion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hivernage* a une signification spécifique dans les pays tropicaux. On la trouve dans le [TLFi](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/hivernage):

> **Hivernage**
> ...
> 2. CLIMATOL. Saison pluvieuse des pays tropicaux. *Nous étions dans la saison de l'hivernage, et conséquemment des orages et des ouragans; mais nous ne nous étions pas attendus à éprouver des temps aussi constamment mauvais* (Voy. La Pérouse,t. 3, 1797, p. 244). *L'hivernage s'avançait, traversé d'immenses rafales de vent qui poussaient devant elles les nuages, et ils ne crevaient pas* (Psichari, Voy. Centur.,1914, p. 48).

*[Fécond](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/f%C3%A9cond)* a son sens figuré habituel.

Dans le tweet en question, le président nigérien fait donc le vœu que la saison des pluies en cours ([juillet, août, septembre](https://reca-niger.org/IMG/pdf/bulletin_de_previsions_saisonnieres_2021_niger._final.pdf)) soit bénéfique aux agriculteurs et éleveurs, apportant abondance de récoltes et de naissances chez les animaux.

Answer (score 0):

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/hivernage)) **2.** **hivernage** [À propos de pers.; correspond à hiverner A 1 b]
> ♦ Il va à Nice, cette fois, et espère dans ce dernier hivernage, clôturer la série de ses hivers loin de Paris.   (Goncourt, Journal,1895, p. 855)
> ♦ Je me décide à lui parler de ce projet d'hivernage à St.-Clair.  (Gide, Journal,1916, p. 569)

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/hiverner))**A** **I** **b)** **hiverner** [Le suj. est une pers.] Passer l'hiver (dans un endroit).
> ♦  Guy de Maupassant m'avoue que Cannes est une fourmilière de renseignements pour lui. Là hivernent les De Luynes, la princesse de Sagan.   (Goncourt, Journal,1884, p. 406)
> ♦ Deux petits garçons (...) visitèrent l'Europe, allant d'hôtel en hôtel, de ville en ville pour hiverner; ils repartaient au printemps, se dirigeaient vers d'autres lieux, selon les caprices du chef de caravane.  (Blanche, Modèles,1928, p. 143)

En utilisant ces définitions et le fait que « hivernage » doit être compris métonymiquement ([métonymie](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%A9tonymie)) comme « période d'activité correspondant à la saison de l'hiver », on peut déduire une expression qui a le même sens, mais plus longue.

- une progression féconde à travers l'hivers
- une période d'activité féconde tout au long de l'hiver

On aurait aussi pu dire la même chose, encore métonymiquement, comme suit.

- un hiver fécond

*Exemple d'usage métonymique*

([réf.](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Deux_soeurs_pour_un_roi/E0XsChIb0cQC?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22un+%C3%A9t%C3%A9+heureux%22&pg=PT251&printsec=frontcover)) Anne était de retour mais il se pouvait que la passion du roi pour elle se fût refroidie après un été heureux.

Answer (score 0):

Dans certains pays africains le terme d'*hivernage* semble faire référence à la saison humide, de juillet à septembre ([Référence](https://www.routard.com/guide/senegal/3260/climat_et_meteo.htm)). Dans le tweet il s'agit de prier pour le retour de la pluie nécessaire aux cultures.